# Data binding cardview control wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here is my xaml

```
 <syncfusion:CardView Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="2"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                             Grid.RowSpan="4"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
            <syncfusion:CardView.DataContext>
                <viewModel:DefaultViewModel />
            </syncfusion:CardView.DataContext>
            <syncfusion:CardView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem.DataContext>
                                <viewModel:DefaultViewModel />
                            </ListBoxItem.DataContext>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Event Name:" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Event Genre:" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventGenre}"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </syncfusion:CardView.ItemTemplate>
            <syncfusion:CardView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </syncfusion:CardView.HeaderTemplate>
</syncfusion:CardView>
```

My viewModel

```
        public DefaultViewModel()
        {
            CustomerDatabaseEntities context = new CustomerDatabaseEntities();
            Events = (from data in context.Event_Details select data.eventTitle).ToList();
        }
        public string EventName {get;set;}
        public string EventGenre {get;set;}
```

My Model

```
public partial class Event_Details
{

    public string eventTitle { get; set; }

    public string eventGenre { get; set; }

}
```

I'm trying to display each value of `eventTitle` and `eventGenre` in its own card similar to this:

[image: Example image].

Each event will have its own card, with its respective details.Although the card view was able to show that i had two different events(refer to link above), both the eventTitle and eventGenre were blank. How would i be able to display each of these values in their own cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Event Name:" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding eventTitle }"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Event Genre:" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding eventGenre }"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```